# ui-select not showing in animated div

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

[In this punk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZkZM8upWWaWH7ErzWWI6?p=preview) I have a `ui-select` in a div that slides from the top (the `ui-select` accepts multiple items). The problem is that it is not displayed. Any ideas how to fix this?

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngSanitize','ngAnimate']);

app.controller('ctl', function($scope) {
  $scope.tags = ['Red','Green','Blue','Maroon','Umbra','Turquoise'];
  $scope.multiple = {};
  $scope.multiple.tags = ['Blue','Red'];
});
```

HTML

```
Open <input type="checkbox" ng-click="opened=!opened">

<div class="panel" ng-show="opened">
    <ui-select multiple ng-model="multiple.tags" style="width:200px;height:30px">
        <ui-select-match>{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="tag in tags | filter:$select.search">
          {{tag}}
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel{
position: fixed;
right: 20px;
top: -2px;
width:400px;
height:300px;
background-color:orange;
}
.panel.ng-hide {
  top: -300px;
}
.panel.ng-hide-add, .panel.ng-hide-remove {
  transition: 0s linear all;
}
.panel.ng-hide-add-active, .panel.ng-hide-remove-active {
transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.panel.ng-show-add-active {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `tagging`(directive) attribute on your `ui-select` element, that will show you selected string options.

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="multiple.tags" tagging style="width:200px;height:30px">
  <ui-select-match>{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="tag in tags | filter:$select.search">
    {{tag}}
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

[**Forked Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/L0AIt22cFZ6UD4kiWYBy?p=preview)